# The "new" keyword means something in ANSI C?

Tags: c

Working on an old code written in ANSI C99 I faced a prototype that I can undestand:

```
short GR_GetX (GR_Block new);
short GR_GetY (GR_Block new);
```

The IDE indicates a warning, but the compiler doens't indicates an error.

There is some advanced interpretation of this keyword, or is just an old error that passes for the compiler?

Comment: `new` is not a C keyword. Were you thinking of C++?

Comment: Make sure your IDE does not think it is C++ code.

Comment: Most likely its syntax highlighting is indiscriminate against C versus C++, so it's raising a warning on a valid C syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` is not part of `C` [keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword).
Your IDE probably tries to parse this file as C++.

Anyway, it's good idea to avoid using C++ [keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) even in C code for better interoperability.

Comment: I wonder what the reasons for the downvotes are? The recommendation not to use C++ keywords in C? That's a good one, **at least** for header files...